# How do I write some code in Linux to automatically open and move 2 windows?

Tags: linux, shell

I'm writing a shell script for a presentation of some of my student's C++ code and I want the script to automatically open the source code and put it on the right half of the monitor, while on the left half is the code being executed in the terminal. I can easily open the two windows, but I don't know how to go about moving them.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Which desktop and window manager are you using?

Comment: Sorry! The program is being run on raspbian on a raspberry pi

Comment: But you still has some desktop environment, or are showing the X11 window remotely on some X11 server (running on the laptop or desktop in front of you, connected to the screen). So my question stays. Read more about [X Window System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) if you are not familiar with it.

Comment: Also, please **edit the question** to improve it by giving the commands used to open the source code and to run the terminal for it.

Comment: If you can install Multi Gnome Terminal, it has a `geometry` [command line option](http://multignometerm.sourceforge.net/web/doc/options.html) which allows positioning and sizing of the window.   There is also a `geometry` option for `lxterminal` (raspbian native terminal), but it doesn't allow positioning.  Documentation [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/lxterminal.1.html).

Comment: Linux doesn't *have* a native concept of a "window" at all. Thus, you need to specify the software you're using (that does understand/create/etc. those) in some detail.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, this help you,

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal --geometry 100x50+0+0 -x sh -c 'cat "$1"; bash' _ "$@"
dirname=$(dirname "$1")
/usr/bin/g++ "$1" -o output 
gnome-terminal --geometry 100x50+1000+0 -x sh -c '"$1/output"; bash' _ "$dirname"
```

run code  as below;

```
./runCode.sh /tmp/test/helloword.c
```

You can also fix --geometry params

Comment: Consider improving your quoting. `sh -c 'cat "$1"; bash' _ "$@"`, for instance, is a replacement for the first line that isn't as prone to shell injection vulnerabilities if your filename passed as `$1` has something like `$(rm -rf $HOME)` as a literal substring.

Comment: similarly, `g++ "$1" -o output`, and `sh -c '"$1/output"; bash' _ "$dirname"`

Comment: ...you might make those `exec bash -i` or similar, too -- no need to keep the copy of `/bin/sh` first spawned as a child to `gnome-terminal` around in memory.

Comment: @charles duffy Thanks